# Php Laravel call a function in the same model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a model with 2 functions. Let's say the model's name is `Cars`. I am trying to call one function `brand` that returns an array so I can use it inside the other `getBrand` function.

```
public static function getBrand($data) {
    $brandVariable = $this->brand(); 
    for ($i=1; $i < count($brandVariable ) ; $i++) { 
        //do something
    }
}

public static function brand() {
    $arrayValues = array(
         1 => 'Brand A',
         2 => 'Brand B',
    );
    return arrayValues;
}
```

Since the values are in `brand` function, I need to pass it inside `getBrand`.

I am getting an error in the `for` loop. I tried in another file (local PHP not Laravel) and it is working fine. But in Laravel, it is not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Cars::brand` because you declared functions as static

```
public static function getBrand($data=null) {
    $Cars = new Cars();
    $brandVariable = $Cars::brand(); 
    for ($i=1; $i < count($brandVariable ) ; $i++) { 
        //do something
    }
}
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/856708

Or

```
public static function getBrand($data=null) {
    $brandVariable = Cars::brand(); 
    for ($i=1; $i < count($brandVariable ) ; $i++) { 
        //do something
    }
}
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/856712

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `brand` inside a static function and `$this` is not available inside the methods declared as `static`.

Since `brand` is declared as a static function you can use one of the following methods to call the function

if within the class

```
self::brand();
```

or

```
static::brand();
```

from outside of the class

```
ClassName::brand();
```

Answer (score 3):

the functions are static so you should use

`self::brand()`

instead of

`$this->brand()`